# Canvas not rendering inside g with transform

Tags: css, canvas, three.js, transform

please save my sanity!

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="sake" stroke-opacity="0.3" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

<g id="1" class="squaregroup" transform="translate(300, 20)">
        <g id="square_main_1" class="square_main" transform="translate(250, 50)">
                <foreignObject class="" id="fo_1" style="width: 500px; height:500px;">
                        <div id="globe" style="width:100%; height:100%" ></div>
                </foreignObject>
        </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

A working simplified jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/n6erd5dq/6/

The canvas works (albeit the globe is only a few pixels in the bottom right corner) and draws the right ThreeJS world, but it never renders inside the parent DIV.

If you inspect the body elements, you can see the DIV is translated right and down a bit.

I've tried so many options of position, absolute, max-width, div clear, changing hierarchy, etc, every trick I know.  From what I see, canvas should honour a foreignObject which honours transform/translate.

Nor can I find any other question on this, so I wonder if I'm doing something SO wrong that no one else has come across this?

I know an alternative is to have one canvas for the entire screen and then multiple viewports (?) for each little image, but given the rest of the project I'm trying to stay away from this.
e.g. https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_elements.html

Many Thanks
Andy

Comment: Why are you putting the div and canvas inside the svg? I have never seen it done like this before, and can't think of why you would want to.

Comment: I'm making an interactive interface.  
-The "square_main" is one of many.
-Each square is draggable to a new position
-The bigger 'squaregroup' is also zoomable/draggable to move around the workspace as a whole

Each square can be a div if text based, a svg/g if d3 based, and in this case I'm building a ThreeJS option.

I've tried swapping the foreignObject for a canvas but no luck (plus the code I've read, including my limited understanding of the ThreeJS book I bought) uses code that grabs a div and adds a canvas.  Would it work if I just mapped ThreeJS to an existing canvas?

Comment: yes you can use three.js in an existing canvas, check the [documentation on WebGLRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer). A It's still not clear why you need it in an svg.

Comment: Appreciate the efforts guys.
I ended up with multiple viewports.